# Can't do string formatting when it comes to modify parameters

Tags: vba, string-formatting

I'm trying to do string formatting using vba. What I'm trying to do is use `productId` within `payload`. It seems I'm close but I can't make it the way I need it.

I've tried with:

```
Sub modifyParams()
    Dim Payload$, productId$
    
    productId = "6000196167258"
    
    Payload = "{""fsa"":""L5V"",""products"":[{""productId"":" & productId & ",""skuIds"":[""6000196167259""]}],""lang"":""en"",""pricingStoreId"":""1061"",""fulfillmentStoreId"":""1061"",""experience"":""whiteGM""}"
    MsgBox Payload
End Sub
```

This is what it prints:

[image]

However, I wish to get quotation mark ***"*** around productId, which is missing here.

> > How can I put quotation mark around an id using string formatting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use double double quotes, like you have in other places, before and after the `& productId &` section.

```
Payload = "{""fsa"":""L5V"",""products"":[{""productId"":""" & productId & """,""skuIds"":[""6000196167259""]}],""lang"":""en"",""pricingStoreId"":""1061"",""fulfillmentStoreId"":""1061"",""experience"":""whiteGM""}"
```

Comment: I wouldn't have figured it out myself. Thanks @Will Walsh, for you excellent solution. It worked perfectly.

Comment: You're welcome @MITHU. I've had issues like that in the past many times. Sometimes just needs a second pair of eyes.

Comment: Remember - odd number of quotes beginning/end of a string, and even number of quotes within a string.